# PHP - Shorten whole number

Tags: php, numbers

I have looked at php round function and I don't think it does what I need it to, I don't want to round to a decimal place I wish to do the following:

```
$variable1 = 200000000 into 200
$variable2 = 20000000 into 20
$variable3 = 2000000 into 2
$variable4 = 200000 into 0.2
```

Could someone help me?

I should add that I will not know what the variable will be so it could be 20000000 one time and the next 380000000

Comment: Divide by a million?

Comment: cant you simply divide this by a million?

Answer (score 2):

[Divide](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.div.php) the number over `1000000`.

```
$num /= 1000000;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$millionDivide = 1000000;

echo $variable1 = 200000000/$millionDivide;
echo $variable2 = 20000000/$millionDivide;
echo $variable3 = 2000000/$millionDivide;
echo $variable4 = 200000/$millionDivide;
```